# Finding the last value in a row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a row containing data in sets of four cells; port code, distance override, time of arrival and time of departure. The distance override columns can be empty.

The idea is to populate columns F and G with the first and last ports in the list (to feed to a filter system in a userform that's so beyond me that I'm trying not to think about it for now).

[image: Column example]

The cell in column F is a simple reference to column H. I used the method from [Last value](https://exceljet.net/formula/get-value-of-last-non-empty-cell) (`=LOOKUP(2,1/(3:3<>""),3:3)`) to get the last value in the row, which works fine. Unfortunately the last value is the time of departure, while what I need is the port code. I've tried adding `-3` in a few different places in the formula, but I can't seem to make it go...

I *could* adjust the order of the columns to put the port code at the end, but I'd like to keep it as it is as the task spec stipulates this order.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Better use `=MATCH(1E+99,3:3)` if the last value is numeric or `=MATCH("zzz",3:3)` for text (or wrap both in a `MAX` to be independant). Also this should be much faster. And to get the value (`MATCH` returns the column number) simply put it in an `INDEX` like `=INDEX(3:3,1,MATCH(1E+99,3:3))` ;)

Comment: @DirkReichel why did you not put that as an answer?  The only thing I would adjust is instead of using 3:3, I would add the column letter at each end of the range in case some text get added in a column off to the right at a later date.

Comment: Ah, excellent. I haven't a clue why it works - haven't seen "zzz" used as a wildcard before - but it does. If you'd like to post it as an answer I'll get it ticked. I'm using `=INDEX(3:3,1,MATCH("zzz",3:3))` and getting the right answer.

Comment: It's not a wildcard, "zzz" is a string which sorts last after other strings, add more z's if you had zzz in your data. When MATCH doesn't find an exact match, the default is to return the last item in the range, in this case the last string. So if all of you data in 3:3 is numerical, except for Port, then Dirk has your answer.

Comment: Aaaah, so that's how it works. Sneaky. I like it. :-)

Comment: I want to copy and paste dirks comment as an answer so the question will appeared as answered, but I cant take credit for his work.  And as for sneaky, that is just the tip of the Excel sneakiness iceburg!

Comment: I may well need more of that sneakiness in the next few days. Next project is a userform with filters and things... I'm dreading it already.

Comment: @ForwardEd Nonono... it is always a bad option to post a comment from a different user as an answer. I've seen votes from below -20 in less than 10 minutes. This way, even if that may sound like a good idea, never forget that there are lots of users who are just waiting to down vote someone (without leaving a reason). Still... I wouldn't care if you do. All I need are 50+ points at all to be able to write comments. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My comment was more a suggestion than a full solution, but if that is all you need to solve your problem, then I'll post it as an answer.

For getting the last entry in a row / column  a fast solution is match. In your case:

```
get the last numerical value: =MATCH(1E+99,3:3)
get the last string:          =MATCH("zzz",3:3)
```

The way it works also is pretty simple: `MATCH` simply loops through all cells till it finds a value which is the same or bigger than the search term for the first option or for the second option till it finds a perfect match or a string which would be "sorted" after the search term. Assuming there is no possible match in range, it will point at the last cell which can be compared (as numerical value). However, both formulas will error out if there is nothing found in the whole range (no number first option and no string for the second) and also keep in mind that `=""` (empty string) will still count as a string.
If there is a possibility for the whole range to not have one of them then you need the full term:

```
=MAX(IFERROR(MATCH("zzz",A:A),0),IFERROR(MATCH(1E+99,A:A),0))
```

However, this will only return the last column as number. to also get the value, you can simply put this inside an `INDEX` like this:

```
=INDEX(3:3,1,MAX(IFERROR(MATCH("zzz",A:A),0),IFERROR(MATCH(1E+99,A:A),0)))
```

If you still have any questions, just ask ;)